# Venue seating maps

Tags: jquery-plugins

I would like to ask for suggestion for any 3rd party plugins or software to could help with the generation of interactive seating maps.

Something like where an admin can draw out a venue and create the seating areas/seats , give them names / prices for each section.

I would appreciate a few pointers.

Thanks

Comment: did you manage to find any solution as I am looking for the same.

Answer (score 0):

There is [JQuery-Seat-Plan](https://github.com/mateuszmarkowski/jQuery-Seat-Charts) plugin and with a little of customization, you can make event organizer be able to design his own seat map.

I'm currently doing something like this.